# Multiple Sql Insert String And RollBack With Catch(Exception)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

If I have to insert with two sql table and the place of string is as below:

```
// Single Record Insert
String  AA=”Insert into aa(date)values(@date)”;

//Multiple Record Insert with datagridview1
For(int i=0;i<datagridview1.rows.count-1;i++)
{
String BB= “insert into bb(name,amount)values(@name,@amount)”;
}
```

If there are two different strings of sql  insert  as per as above by single and multiple insert on Button click Event  than Is it possible to handle it on single sql command if yes than reply how?.

But as per I think it is not possible by single SqlCommand and if it is true than there are very big problem to adjust  SqlTransaction Class for Rollback and Commit. with try and catch block of the EventHandller

I am really struggling to insert multiple  sql statement  as  above at one Button1_Click Event. Suggest me proper solution or proper way , technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly define the transactions in your ADO.NET Code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection  db = new SqlConnection("constring");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand();
        SqlTransaction tran;
        db.Open();
        tran = db.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            //Run all your insert statements here here
            com.CommandText = "Insert into a(Date) Values(@Date)";
            com.Connection = db;
            com.Transaction = tran;
            com.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            com.Parameters["@Date"].Value = DateTime.Now;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            com2.CommandText = "Insert into bb(name,amount) values(@name, @amount)";
            com2.Connection = db;
            com2.Transaction = tran;
            com2.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
            com2.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Decimal);

            for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //on each loop replace @name value and @amount value with appropiate
                //value from your row collection
                com2.Parameters["@name"].Value = datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["Name"].Value; 
                com2.Parameters["@amount"].Value = datagrid.Rows[i].Cells["Amount"].Value;
                com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice but I think You are missing multiple record insert statement in for loop block. I wants first string on single insert and another at multiple row insert. Suppose if Datagridview1 have 10 rows at collection than I would like to insert 10 rows not single.

Comment: So for the second insert statement, are you looking simply looking to insert 10 rows or are you trying to insert 10 rows using only one sql statement?  If you are trying to use one sql statement, what is the reason that it needs to be a single statement?

Comment: See It's just example of 10 rows. it's not fixed it may be 10,20, or less than 5, that's why there is for loop require for  insert multiple records by collection of rows count.

Comment: Ok, I just added code to put a for loop around the second insert statement.  I think this will do what you want.